# uppercase and lowercase not working in Contains in Aws dynamoDB?

Tags: case, amazon-dynamodb, contains

I have a DynamoDB database with an attribute `Event_Name` which has uppercase values, for example `KRISHNA`. When I specify a Scan FilterExpression comparitor `CONTAINS` with a lowercase value, for example `krishna`, the item with value `KRISHNA` is not returned. When I use the uppercase value it returns the item. Please help me.

For reference my code is:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "User",
    FilterExpression: "NOT userId in (:a) and contains(Event_Name, :name)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":a": {
            S: $scope.userid
        },
        ":name": {
            S: namekey
        }
    }
};
```

using dynamodb scan method

Comment: Hi @SanthanaKrishnan, if I know it's a lot of time since you asked this question, but if you are still around could you please accept the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you already figured out, but since I stumbled upon this question and it's not closed, here is a link in AWS forum addressing the issue

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=92159

> DynamoDB is case sensitive. If your data is case insensitive, one solution is to lower case or upper case the data before storing it in DynamoDB. Then you can get around this by querying for all lower case or all upper case. You will need to take locale into account for locale-sensitive ordering.

So there is nothing wrong you are doing, you just were expecting something that is not available with DynamoDB